Piped dd command limits its output to 65536 bytes, why?
My colleague and I are both using a Docker container running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish):
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# grep VERSION= /etc/os-release 
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

Now, assume we have a binary file of 98299904 bytes in that Docker container:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd if=/dev/urandom of=randomfile bs=1 count=98299904
98299904+0 records in
98299904+0 records out
98299904 bytes (98 MB, 94 MiB) copied, 101.014 s, 973 kB/s
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# ls -al randomfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 98299904 May 29 19:17 randomfile

We can then extract a certain part of that binary file with dd.  Let's do that in 2619 blocks of size 12624 and let's skip the first block:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd if=randomfile of=test1 ibs=12624 skip=1 count=2619 obs=33061608
2619+0 records in
1+1 records out
33062256 bytes (33 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.0745345 s, 444 MB/s

Note that although we specified obs=33061608, we get an output file of size 2619*12624=33062256 bytes, which is larger then the 33061608 we requested.  Therefore, we try to chop off the first 33061608 bytes of that first dd output by piping its output to a second dd command:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd if=randomfile ibs=12624 skip=1 count=2619 obs=33061608 | dd bs=33061608 count=1 of=test2
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
65536 bytes (66 kB, 64 KiB) copied, 0.0526223 s, 1.2 MB/s
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# ls -al test2 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 65536 May 29 19:23 test2

Unfortunately, what do we see?  The resulting output file is only 65536 bytes large instead of our expected 33061608.
Now, the strange thing is that this on my system I get this faulty 65536 bytes output, but on my colleague his system (which uses exactly the same Docker container with the same version of dd), he gets the expected 33061608 bytes output.
Also, when I do it in two steps with an intermediate file and not using the pipe operator, then things seem to work:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd if=randomfile ibs=12624 skip=1 count=2619 obs=33061608 of=test1
2619+0 records in
1+1 records out
33062256 bytes (33 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.0321817 s, 1.0 GB/s
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# ls -al test1 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33062256 May 29 19:39 test1
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd if=test1 of=test2 bs=33061608 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
33061608 bytes (33 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.0264926 s, 1.2 GB/s
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# ls -al test2 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33061608 May 29 19:39 test2

Also, replacing the second dd command with head -c seems to work in combination with the pipe operator:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd if=randomfile ibs=12624 skip=1 count=2619 obs=33061608 | head -c 33061608 > test2       
2619+0 records in
1+1 records out
33062256 bytes (33 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.0691351 s, 478 MB/s
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# ls -al test2 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33061608 May 29 19:43 test2

We're currently in the dark what is causing this behavior.  The 65536 size of the faulty output from the second piped dd command is suspicious (65536=2^16), but we don't understand what's the root cause of this.  It is a limitation from dd or is it a limitation with the pipe operator that we use to pipe the output of the first dd command to the second dd?  How can I make my second piped dd command work?
The version of dd that our Docker container has is:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# dd --version | head -1
dd (coreutils) 8.32

The version of bash that our Docker container has is:
root@c2155d7af4a4:/# /bin/bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)


What kernel version is your colleague running? While my current answer explains why it doesn't work on your system, I suspect a difference there might explain why it happens to work on his.

I just tested it and with iflag=fullblock it indeed works on my system.  I am running "Linux b715db5f0532 5.15.0-107-generic #117~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 30 10:35:57 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux".  I will ask my colleague tomorrow what kernel he is running.

I got feedback from my colleague for whom it works: his output for uname -a is "Linux PC-2314 5.4.0-182-generic #202-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 26 12:29:36 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" so he's running a slightly older kernel than me...

I'm at a loss as to how it could be working for him. Can you upload the result of running strace -f bash -c 'dd if=randomfile ibs=12624 skip=1 count=2619 obs=33061608 | dd bs=33061608 count=1 of=test2' on the box where it works?

From the coreutils gotchas:

dd
dd iflag=fullblock is usually what you want because when reading from a fifo/pipe you often get a short read, which means you get too little data if you specify "count"

The problem is that dd bs=33061608 count=1 tries to do one 33061608-byte read, and without iflag=fullblock, if (when) a partial read happens, it won't do any more reads to get the rest of the data. So to make it work, just add that to the second dd.
